# Is using dbms_utility.format_error_stack to filter errors in the exception block a bad idea?

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception

I'm trying to handle two different exceptions could trigger in an external table that reads a CSV.

The code works great, but I'm concerned I'm doing it wrong.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  records INT := 0;  
  external_table EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(external_table, -29913);    
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO records FROM ext_testing;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN external_table THEN
      IF dbms_utility.format_error_stack LIKE '%KUP-04040%' THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Missing CSV file!');
      ELSIF dbms_utility.format_error_stack LIKE '%ORA-30653%' THEN
          raise_application_error(-20001, 'Invalid UTI report, check for missing fields!');
      END IF;      
    WHEN others THEN      
        dbms_output.put_line('An exception occurred');
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE || '=>' || SQLERRM);        
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest two small modifications:

- re-raise the exception in the `WHEN OTHERS` exception handler. Not raising the exception will make the calling application think that the procedure did succeed. Or better yet don't use `WHEN OTHERS`: there's no point in catching an exception if you do nothing but re-raise it. Let the natural exception bubble up.
- add an `ELSE` clause in the first exception handler just to be sure that you don't silently ignore a new type of error that doesn't get catched by the two `IF` conditions.

Aside from that, I don't see anything wrong with using `dbms_utility.format_error_stack` in an exception clause (in fact you can't use it anywhere else).

```
EXCEPTION
   WHEN external_table THEN
      IF dbms_utility.format_error_stack LIKE '%KUP-04040%' THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Missing CSV file!');
      ELSIF dbms_utility.format_error_stack LIKE '%ORA-30653%' THEN
         raise_application_error(-20001, 'Invalid UTI report, check for missing fields!');
      ELSE
         raise_application_error(-20002, 
                                 'An exception occurred: ' || SQLERRM,
                                 TRUE);
      END IF;
   -- WHEN OTHERS THEN -- No point really
   --    raise_application_error(-20003, 
   --                            'An unknown exception occurred: ' || SQLERRM,
   --                            TRUE);
END;
```